# Preventing form submission and triggering an error if certain checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript

I am trying to prevent form submission and triggering a span error if certain checkbox is checked. if checkboxes are 3,4 and 6 are selected. Please note that there are two error message one for each checkbox group.

```
<form action="" method="" role="form" name="form1">               
    <span id="sprycheckbox1">
        <span class="checkbox-error hide">
            Your answer contains a wrong selection. Please try again.
        </span>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
        <label for="checkbox">checkbox1</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
        <label for="checkbox">checkbox2</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
        <label for="checkbox">checkbox3</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox4">
        <label for="checkbox">checkbox4</label><br>
    </span>

    <span id="sprycheckbox2">
        <span class="checkbox-error hide">
            Your answer contains a wrong selection. Please try again.
        </span>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox5">
        <label for="checkbox">checkbox5</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox6">
        <label for="checkbox">checkbox6</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox7">
        <label for="checkbox">checkbox7</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox8">
        <label for="checkbox">checkbox8</label><br>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox9">
        <label for="checkbox">checkbox9</label><br>
    </span>


    <br><br>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-natio general-btn-extra-padding" onclick="validateSubmission()">NEXT</button></form>

function validateSubmission() {
    var checkboxSelected = document.getElementById('checkbox6').checked;
    if(checkboxSelected) {
      $('span.checkbox-error').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
      $('span.checkbox-error').addClass('hide');
      // submit your form here like below
      var forms = document.getElementsByName('form1');
      forms[0].submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: anddd your Question issss

Comment: cant get the error to trigger if certain checkboxes are checked. In this case it's checkboxes id checkbox1, checkbox3 and checkbox6. I know that I have to refined the js but I am kind of stuck @M.chaudhry

Comment: question like this gets posted every other day here. You do it in two steps...cancel the event, check for whatever, then if happy initiate submit manually.

Comment: the js will only work if id=checkbox6 is checked but how do I add checkbox id 1 and 3 so error will trigger if any of those are checked, please note that there are two different error message for each checkbox group which will need to customised.

Comment: function validateSubmission() {
    var checkboxSelected = document.getElementById('checkbox6').checked;
    if(checkboxSelected) {
      $('span.checkbox-error').removeClass('hide');
    } else {
      $('span.checkbox-error').addClass('hide');
      // submit your form here like below
      var forms = document.getElementsByName('form1');
      forms[0].submit();
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use onsubmit event of form that will occur when form is going to submit, simply return false in case anything is wrong.

`<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-natio general-btn-extra-padding" onsubmit="return validateSubmission()">NEXT</button>`

```
function validateSubmission() {

    int isValid = false;

    // Validation Logic

    if(!isValid) {
      // Show Error Message
      return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function validateSubmission() {
    if($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length) {
        $('span.checkbox-error').removeClass('hide');
        alert("Please select at least one to upgrade.");

        //stop the form from submitting
        return false;
    }
else {
      $('span.checkbox-error').addClass('hide');
      // submit your form here like below
     return true;
    }
});
```